# What are the most cost efficient thermostatic valve values for UFH?

Tags: radiant-heating, hydronic, zoned-heating, floorheating

The manifolds on each floor have a thermostatic valve. I recall reading somewhere that for the most efficient system that you set these to the lowest acceptable value. I have these set to 35*C. The boiler is set to 60*C as it is also heating the hot water for showers.

I’ve noticed if I increase the value on the thermostatic valves to 45*C that the boiler is on less as it’s calling for heat less, which makes sense.

So my question is:

- In order to minimize cost, should the thermostatic valves be set to the lowest accept value?
- Given the boiler is heating the water to 60*C and the valves are at 35*C where is the excess energy going?

I feel (rather stupidly) that I’m missing a key bit of information…

A picture of one of the manifolds (they are all setup the same):

[image]

Comment: I feel that _we_ are missing some info. What are you attempting to do? What kind of efficiency are you looking for?

Comment: a pic of your system would help.  do you have a buffer tank?

Comment: how long does your boiler run for typically before turning off in the two different configurations less than 60 seconds? more than 3 minutes?

Comment: Presumably you have a circulator for the floor loop(s) and your mixing valve is pulling in hot water (or having it pushed in by another circulator) to raise the return from the floor to the setpoint temperature, by blending in 60°C boiler water?

Comment: @FreeMan - cost efficiency is what I am after.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - longer than 3 minutes for both. There is no buffer tank.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I believe the answer is yes to this. Regardless of whether a zone is calling for heat, if another zone is calling for heat then hot water is circulating to each manifold.

Comment: @All - sorry I thought it would be a standard setup so therefore I may have missed information out.

Comment: Best to [edit] that info into the question itself, @Cheetah. I've done that for you this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thermostatic mixing valve takes the return water and mixes it with the supply water in order to get as close to the right temp as possible.

Let's take the maximal example, if you take 60C water and run it through your loops, the zones will quickly reach temperature and stop calling for hot water.  Your boiler will turn off, the zones will cool down and call for heat again.  Your zones will likely over heat and not call for heat for a longer period of time.  Your boiler run time will be lower.

On the other hand, if you take 35C water and run it through your loops, the zones will be slower to reach temperature and not over heat and your boiler is going to run for longer as the return water temperature is going to be lower.  The zone will also continue to call for heat longer as it isn't overheating.  The boiler will run for longer in that cycle but I expect the time in between the boiler running will be longer as the heat will have more time to charge all the surfaces in the house up to 35C.

Assuming your system is air sensor driven the 45C water will charge the air quicker, turn off the boiler, but will dissipate that heat quicker as it was running for less time and dissipate to the colder areas in your house.

If you boiler has an overall run time higher at 45C over a period of time than having it run at 35C then it is more efficient at 35C.

The least cost efficient way to heat is to have a larger delta T.  The lower the delta T the slower the heat loss and the more cost efficient.

Heatgeek has some interesting graphs in terms of boiler efficiency.  It seems like as long as your boiler fires for 3m or greater you have 100% efficiency on the operational side.  Short cycling the boiler will have an effect as well but it looks like once you pass the boiler running for 3m the effect is negligible.

[image: efficiency degredation]

Comment: There are air sensors for most zones except bathrooms where there are floor sensors. I have the temperature set to around 21*C.